# Exit of an infinite loop

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, exit

My code below makes some string manipulation. My problem is that I want to exit of the program if no rhythm and/or text is typed. In other words, if I press ENTER (new line) and nothing was typed to be read for scanf(), then the program must finish.As you see, I set a condition that when rhythm is not between the range[2,6], the program is finished.

```
int main()
{
   char text[80]; // To storage the text string 
   int rhythm; // To storage the rhythm value
   int k;
   banner();
   for( ; ; ){
        scanf("%i %79[^\n]", &rhythm, text);
        if(rhythm < 2 || rhythm > 6) break; // Termination of loop 
        printf("%s\n", text); // Printing original text
        conversion(text, rhythm); 
        printf("%s\n\n", text); // Printing modified text      
   }
   bye();     
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps check the result of [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (which you should be doing anyway, as you can't trust your variables unless it reports it actually scanned something *in to* them).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if(rhythm < 2 || rhythm > 6 || text[0] == "\n") break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `scanf` directly, which does not work if the user want to end with <kbd>Enter</kbd>,  I recommend you to read the whole line, analyze it with `sscanf` and use the return values of these functions:

```
 char buffer[255];

 for( ; ; ){
      if(!fgets(buffer,255,stdin))
         break;
      s=sscanf(buffer,"%i %79[^\n]", &rhythm, text);
      if (s!=2)
         break;
      // ...   
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not use a `for` loop in this case :

```
do
{
   ...
}
while(rhythm >= 2 && rhythm <= 6);
```

Comment: That was not was he was asking for.

Comment: True, but, I am sorry, that's what really shocked me. :/ I don't expect this answer to be THE answer, but juste an advise.

Comment: To my experience endless for-loop with exit in the middle is the most suitable kind of loop for input-processing-output kind of work. Nothing beats it.